# microk8s, DEVOPS : Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for <internal IPs>, not <external IP>

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, microk8s

I have a microk8s cluster on a ubuntu laptop.
I want to apply a deployment yaml file on it from azure devops pipeline.

I have successfully defined a  Kubernetes Service connections in my devops and it went through verification. Though when I try to apply the yaml file I get these lines

```
/usr/bin/kubectl apply -f /home/vsts/work/1/s/devops/deploymen.yaml -o json


##[error]Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, 10.152.183.1, 192.168.50.69, 172.17.0.1, 10.1.80.0, not <my external IP>
```

192.168.50.69 is the ip of the laptop in my network

Where should I add my external IP?

**EDIT :**

I found [Authentication and authorization](https://microk8s.io/docs/ports#heading--auth) and I edited  `/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/csr.conf.template` so it includes my IP now.

The article says :

> After changing, the apiserver-kicker will automatically detect the difference, generate new certs and restart the apiserver. Your DNS server settings and **kubeconfig** file must be updated appropriately.

The certificate in certificate-authority-data  `/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/ca.crt` now looks different than the one from   `microk8s config`

I also updated **kubeconfig** with as mentioned above

But still no luck !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The solution from these issues is to modify the template and add the missing IP address

`/var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/csr.conf.template`

```sh
...

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = kubernetes
DNS.2 = kubernetes.default
DNS.3 = kubernetes.default.svc
DNS.4 = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster
DNS.5 = kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
IP.1 = 127.0.0.1
IP.2 = 192.168.1.1
IP.100 = 192.168.1.1 # USE IP > 100
#MOREIPS

...
```

> When you modify this template files, microk8s daemon generates a new `csr.conf`

This happens because if you check the `sudo cat /var/snap/microk8s/current/certs/csr.conf` file the ID of the IP you are assigning is taken by another IP.

To solve this collision, a higher ID must be used and this will work

Answer (score 8):

I reproduced your issue and the solution seems to be either adding certificate in kubeconfig file or to skip tls verification.

You can do it by adding `insecure-skip-tls-verify: true` to kubeconfig file so it look something like this:

```
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://<master_ip>:<port>
```

or modify `kubeconfig` on your microk8s cluster and change `server: https://127.0.0.1:16443` to `server: https://<master_ip>:16443` and copy it to the host you want to access cluster from.

Comment: Thank you that is nice I am at least up and running although it is insecure. I was wondering how can I "adding certificate in kubeconfig"  is that the same certificate that I mentioned above in that case I run 
$ kubectl config set-cluster microk8s-cluster  --certificate-authority=home/daniel/.kube/kubernetes.ca.crt --embed-certs=true  , it says config file is updated but it is keep being the same old one

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue on a single node, not a cluster, when I joined another wireless network and received an ip-address in a different network-scope. Found the solution at [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/docs/command-reference#heading--microk8s-refresh-certs). Command is

```
sudo microk8s refresh-certs -e ca.crt
microk8s config > ~/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 1):

The microk8s documentation has a [troubleshooting guide for this error](https://microk8s.io/docs/troubleshooting):

> **I get "Unable to connect to the server: x509" on a multi-node cluster**
>
> This indicates that the certificates are not being regenerated correctly to reflect network changes. A workaround is to temporarily rename the file found at:
>
> `/var/snap/microk8s/current/var/lock/no-cert-reissue`
>
> The certificates should then be automatically regenerated. The above file can then be returned to its original name.

I followed accepted answer but that didn't seem to be enough to regenerate the certificates. Renaming this file to a new name and back solved it for me.

Comment: Nothing is working for me and `/var/snap/microk8s/current/var/lock/no-cert-reissue` doesn't exist...

Comment: Cheers, Renaming the "no-cert-reissue" file worked perfectly for a multi-node cluster and resulted in the csr.conf being auto-regenerated.

Comment: Note: You will need to repeat this step for each node in the cluster.